# Checking segment length in dataframe 1 against multiple segment instances in dataframe 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Background:** I have two Pandas DataFrames:

- DF1 represents known road segments with >= 7% truck traffic.
- DF2 represents all road segments in the study area.

**Columns:** `SRI` is 'standard route identifier', `MP_START` is 'mile point start', `MP_END` is 'mile point end', and `TRUCK_PCT` is 'truck traffic percentage'.

**Task:** For each row in `DF1`, the task is to check each record in `DF2` to find two concurrent items:

1. Find matching `SRI` records.
2. Within the matching `SRI` records, find the rows in `DF2` where `DF1.MP_START` and `DF1.MP_END` values are present within the `DF2.MP_START` and `DF2.MP_END` values.
3. Then assign the `DF1.TRUCK_PCT` value to the correct row in `DF2` following the above condition. An example follows below.

**Sample DF1:**

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame([['00000009__', 51.30, 52.26, '7%'], 
                   ['00000015__', 14.41, 14.71,'12%'], 
                   ['00000015__', 14.71, 15.45,'8%'],
                   ['00000015__', 15.45, 15.724,'7%'],
                   ['00000015__', 15.72, 16.25,'8%'],
                   ['00000015__', 16.25, 16.31,'10%'],
                   ['00000015__', 16.31, 16.70, '10%'],
                   ['00000015__', 16.70, 16.89,'11%']], columns=['SRI', 'MP_START', 'MP_END', 'TRUCK_PCT'])
```

---

```
         SRI   MP_START MP_END  TRUCK_PCT
0   00000009__  51.30   52.260  7%
1   00000015__  14.41   14.710  12%
2   00000015__  14.71   15.450  8%
3   00000015__  15.45   15.724  7%
4   00000015__  15.72   16.250  8%
5   00000015__  16.25   16.310  10%
6   00000015__  16.31   16.700  10%
7   00000015__  16.70   16.890  11%
```

**Sample DF2:**

```
DF2 = pd.DataFrame([['17031021__', 0.0, 0.10], 
                   ['03291236__', 0.0, 0.05], 
                   ['200006165__', 0.0, 0.12],
                   ['00000009__', 52.36, 52.394],
                   ['00000009__', 51.78, 52.36],
                   ['00000009__', 49.09, 51.78],
                   ['00000009__', 48.76, 48.76],
                   ['00000015__', 15.45, 15.48]], columns=['SRI', 'MP_START', 'MP_END'])
```

---

```
    SRI       MP_START  MP_END
0   17031021__  0.00    0.100
1   03291236__  0.00    0.050
2   200006165__ 0.00    0.120
3   00000009__  52.36   52.394
4   00000009__  51.78   52.360
5   00000009__  49.09   51.780
6   00000009__  48.76   48.760
7   00000015__  15.45   15.480
```

---

**Expected result:**

- For the row where `DF1.SRI == 00000009__`, `DF1.MP_START == 51.30` and `DF1.MP_END == 52.260`:

  `DF1.MP_START` on row 0 (`51.30`) falls within row 5 of `DF2` and `DF1.MP_END` of row 0 (`52.26`) falls within row 4. Therefore, both `DF2` rows 4 and 5 are assigned a `TRUCK_PCT` value of 7%.
- Similarly, where `DF2.SRI == 00000015__` (row 7) this row would be assigned a `TRUCK_PCT` of 7% because row 3 of `DF1` contains `MP_START` and `MP_END` values of `DF2` where `DF1.SRI == DF2.SRI (00000015__)`.

**Sample DF3 Output:**

```
    SRI       MP_START  MP_END  TRUCK_PCT
0   17031021__  0.00    0.100   
1   03291236__  0.00    0.050
2   200006165__ 0.00    0.120
3   00000009__  52.36   52.394
4   00000009__  51.78   52.360   7%
5   00000009__  49.09   51.780   7%
6   00000009__  48.76   48.760
7   00000015__  15.45   15.480   7%
```

**Disclaimer:** This is a confusing problem - please ask for more info where needed and I will try and clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to first merge the two dataframes on the SRI column (keeping all rows in `DF2`) and then afterward find which rows fulfill the secondary condition of overlapping ranges.

First, merge the dataframes while keeping the index of `DF2` for later usage:

```
DF2 = DF2.reset_index()
df = pd.merge(DF2, DF1, on='SRI', how='left', suffixes=('', '_range'))
```

This results in the following dataframe:

```
    index          SRI  MP_START  MP_END  MP_START_range  MP_END_range TRUCK_PCT
0       0   17031021__      0.00   0.100             NaN           NaN       NaN
1       1   03291236__      0.00   0.050             NaN           NaN       NaN
2       2  200006165__      0.00   0.120             NaN           NaN       NaN
3       3   00000009__     52.36  52.394           51.30        52.260        7%
4       4   00000009__     51.78  52.360           51.30        52.260        7%
5       5   00000009__     49.09  51.780           51.30        52.260        7%
6       6   00000009__     48.76  48.760           51.30        52.260        7%
7       7   00000015__     15.45  15.480           14.41        14.710       12%
8       7   00000015__     15.45  15.480           14.71        15.450        8%
9       7   00000015__     15.45  15.480           15.45        15.724        7%
10      7   00000015__     15.45  15.480           15.72        16.250        8%
11      7   00000015__     15.45  15.480           16.25        16.310       10%
12      7   00000015__     15.45  15.480           16.31        16.700       10%
13      7   00000015__     15.45  15.480           16.70        16.890       11%
```

Now, we create a boolean index for the rows that have `MP_START` or `MP_END` within the two range columns. Any row that does not fulfill one of these conditions have their `TRUCK_PCT` value set to nan:

```
cond_start = (df['MP_START'] >= df['MP_START_range']) & (df['MP_START'] < df['MP_END_range'])
cond_end = (df['MP_END'] >= df['MP_START_range']) & (df['MP_END'] < df['MP_END_range'])
df.loc[~(cond_start | cond_end), 'TRUCK_PCT'] = np.nan
```

Finally, we can drop the two range columns and group by the previously created index to get the final result. This will preserve any rows in `DF2` that do not have a match in `DF1`:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['MP_START_range', 'MP_END_range']).groupby('index').first().fillna('')
```

Result:

```
               SRI  MP_START  MP_END TRUCK_PCT
index                                         
0       17031021__      0.00   0.100          
1       03291236__      0.00   0.050          
2      200006165__      0.00   0.120          
3       00000009__     52.36  52.394          
4       00000009__     51.78  52.360        7%
5       00000009__     49.09  51.780        7%
6       00000009__     48.76  48.760          
7       00000015__     15.45  15.480        7%
```

Comment: Brilliant solution! Thank you most kindly!