# Using Pandas, how to calculate a mean of a column across multiple rows when using a conditional statement?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a follow-up question to one I asked yesterday: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66997534/checking-segment-length-in-dataframe-1-against-multiple-segment-instances-in-dat)

**Background:** I have two Pandas DataFrames:

- DF1 represents known road segments with >= 7% truck traffic.
- DF2 represents all road segments in the study area.

**Columns:** `SRI` is 'standard route identifier', `MP_START` is 'mile point start', `MP_END` is 'mile point end', and `TRUCK_PCT` is 'truck traffic percentage'.

**Additional Task**
Currently I am assigning the `DF1.TRUCK_PCT` value from the last row of all matching values. I would like instead to assign the mean of these values. For instance - given these matching rows, **I am currently assigning 7% to the `DF2` record. I would instead like to assign the mean of these records, or 8.75%**

[image: Rows from DF1 that match the distance band found in DF2]

**Question:**

How would I augment these lines of code provided in the previous question to instead calculate the mean?

```
DF2 = DF2.reset_index()
df = pd.merge(DF2, DF1, on='SRI', how='left', suffixes=('', '_range'))

cond_start = (df['MP_START'] >= df['MP_START_range']) & (df['MP_START'] < df['MP_END_range'])
cond_end = (df['MP_END'] >= df['MP_START_range']) & (df['MP_END'] < df['MP_END_range'])
# This is where the mean calculation would happen, if I knew how to do it
df.loc[~(cond_start | cond_end), 'TRUCK_PCT'] = np.nan

df = df.drop(columns=['MP_START_range', 'MP_END_range']).groupby('index').first().fillna('')
```

**Sample DF1:**

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame([['00000030__', 56.0, 56.51,'8%'], 
                       ['00000030__', 56.51, 56.64,'8%'], 
                       ['00000030__', 56.64, 56.77,'8%'],
                       ['00000031__', 8.59,  10.19,'7%'],
                       ['00000031__', 10.19, 10.49,'9%'],
                       ['00000031__', 10.49, 10.84,'9%'],
                       ['00000031__', 10.84, 11.00,'9%'],
                       ['00000031__', 11.00, 12.00,'9%'],
                       ['00000031__', 12.00, 12.21,'9%'],
                       ['00000031__', 12.21, 12.26,'9%'],
                       ['00000031__', 12.26, 12.27,'9%'],
                       ['00000031__', 12.27, 13.36,'7%'],
                       ['00000031__', 13.36, 13.97,'7%'],
                       ['00000031__', 13.97, 14.83,'7%'],
                       ['00000031__', 14.83, 15.00,'10%']], columns=['SRI', 'MP_START', 'MP_END', 'TRUCK_PCT'])
```

---

```
         SRI  MP_START  MP_END  TRUCK_PCT
0   00000030__  56.00   56.51   8%
1   00000030__  56.51   56.64   8%
2   00000030__  56.64   56.77   8%
3   00000031__  8.59    10.19   7%
4   00000031__  10.19   10.49   9%
5   00000031__  10.49   10.84   9%
6   00000031__  10.84   11.00   9%
7   00000031__  11.00   12.00   9%
8   00000031__  12.00   12.21   9%
9   00000031__  12.21   12.26   9%
10  00000031__  12.26   12.27   9%
11  00000031__  12.27   13.36   7%
12  00000031__  13.36   13.97   7%
13  00000031__  13.97   14.83   7%
14  00000031__  14.83   15.00   10%
```

---

**Sample DF2:**

```
DF2 = pd.DataFrame([['00000031__', 7.14, 7.33], 
                       ['00000031__', 7.33, 7.93], 
                       ['00000031__', 7.93, 8.02],
                       ['00000031__', 8.02, 9.53],
                       ['00000031__', 9.53, 10.19],
                       ['00000031__', 10.19, 10.37],
                       ['00000031__', 10.37, 13.00],
                       ['00000031__', 13.00, 13.70],
                       ['00000031__', 13.70, 13.97],
                       ['00000031__', 13.97, 14.14],
                       ['00000031__', 14.14, 14.77],
                       ['00000031__', 14.77, 14.96],
                       ['00000031__', 14.96, 15.80],
                       ['00000031__', 15.80, 16.03],
                       ['00000031__', 16.03, 16.36]], columns=['SRI', 'MP_START', 'MP_END'])
```

---

```
    SRI      MP_START   MP_END
0   00000031__  7.14    7.33
1   00000031__  7.33    7.93
2   00000031__  7.93    8.02
3   00000031__  8.02    9.53
4   00000031__  9.53    10.19
5   00000031__  10.19   10.37
6   00000031__  10.37   13.00
7   00000031__  13.00   13.70
8   00000031__  13.70   13.97
9   00000031__  13.97   14.14
10  00000031__  14.14   14.77
11  00000031__  14.77   14.96
12  00000031__  14.96   15.80
13  00000031__  15.80   16.03
14  00000031__  16.03   16.36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, change the very last line:

```py
df = df.drop(columns=['MP_START_range', 'MP_END_range']).groupby('index').first().fillna('')
```

To these 3 lines (3rd line is optional, only if you want to convert back to a `%` string):

```py
# convert TRUCK_PCT from % string to float so it can be averaged
df['TRUCK_PCT'] = df['TRUCK_PCT'].str.replace('%', '').astype(float)

# use groupby.mean() instead of groupby.first()
df = df.drop(columns=['MP_START_range', 'MP_END_range']).groupby('index').mean()

# (optional) convert TRUCK_PCT back to % string
df['TRUCK_PCT'] = (df['TRUCK_PCT'].fillna('').astype(str) + '%').str.replace(r'^%$', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
       MP_START  MP_END TRUCK_PCT
index                            
0          7.14    7.33          
1          7.33    7.93          
2          7.93    8.02          
3          8.02    9.53      7.0%
4          9.53   10.19      8.0%
5         10.19   10.37      9.0%
6         10.37   13.00      8.0%
7         13.00   13.70      7.0%
8         13.70   13.97      7.0%
9         13.97   14.14      7.0%
10        14.14   14.77      7.0%
11        14.77   14.96      8.5%
12        14.96   15.80     10.0%
13        15.80   16.03          
14        16.03   16.36
```

So the complete code block looks like this:

```py
DF2 = DF2.reset_index()
df = pd.merge(DF2, DF1, on='SRI', how='left', suffixes=('', '_range'))

cond_start = (df['MP_START'] >= df['MP_START_range']) & (df['MP_START'] < df['MP_END_range'])
cond_end = (df['MP_END'] >= df['MP_START_range']) & (df['MP_END'] < df['MP_END_range'])
df.loc[~(cond_start | cond_end), 'TRUCK_PCT'] = np.nan

df['TRUCK_PCT'] = df['TRUCK_PCT'].str.replace('%', '').astype(float)
df = df.drop(columns=['MP_START_range', 'MP_END_range']).groupby('index').mean()
df['TRUCK_PCT'] = (df['TRUCK_PCT'].fillna('').astype(str) + '%').str.replace(r'^%$', '', regex=True)
```